# FileVault2 effect on speeds

Tags: macos, security, filevault

I would like to know what kind of speed implications using FileVault2 would have on my MBPr (late 2013). As there are much faster SSD's in these machines I want to know whether there is a noticeable speed difference compared older generations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used FileVault 2 on my mid - 2012 retina MBPro. It's been awhile since I activated FileVault 2, but I've seen little to no real performance hit once I activated FV2.

There are some more objective tests available such as [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/10/filevault-2-benchmarks-disk-encryption-faster-mac-os-x-lion/).

Answer (score 1):

I have a 512GB Apple SSD in late-2011 MBP (custom order). I do not have benchmarks but I did not notice any visible slow downs.